# can $_FILES superglobal be accessible in class

Tags: php

Does anyone have experience with this

I wanted to use $_files in my class

like

```
$Uploadfile= $_FILES['file'];
```

but then the script errors

I thought superglobals were acccessible anywhere

thanks, Richard

Comment: Please do share the error. It should be accessible, if it's not it's probably because there is no $_FILES['file']. Try using isset

Comment: I have try'd isset before I call the class and it says yes But then from the class it errors out?

Comment: Well I have a suggestion for you, but it won't let me post an answer... So I wrote it on Snipt instead: snipt.org/orp

Comment: ok, I saw it that was easy. Thank you, learned something again. But it is not competely true that you can not set variables. It is possible to set default values. So you have to explain that a little differently to get the distinction.

Comment: Correct, you can set STATIC variables, but in your case, you're setting it dynamically. To do that, you need to use a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `$_FILES` is a superglobal, which means that it's accessible from every scope. It's only set if the request actually contains a `multipart/form-data` body.

Comment: thanks, actually BraedenP gave me the exact answer. What he sayd was actually, that I had to assign this to a variable from within a class function. Problem Solved.